# Remove $(Platform) from destination file

Tags: msbuild

I have a code to copy propper configuration file on deploy:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
        CopyConfigFiles;
        $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="CopyConfigFiles">
   <ItemGroup>
    <_ConfigFiles Include="Configurations\*.$(Platform).config" />
    <FilesForPackagingFromProject  Include="%(_ConfigFiles.Identity)">
      <DestinationRelativePath>%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
    </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
   </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Is it possible to remove $(Platform) from result files ?

ie.

- $(Platform) = Production
- Source: connectionString.Production.config
- Destination: connectionString.config

Comment: No, even if set to empty, you will have a double `.` in the filename and it will break. `$(Platform)` should either prefix or affix the `.`, then it can be made empty.

Comment: @leppie Well, it's a file. So it can always be renamed. msbuild has Copy and Delete task to do a rename

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to actually reference **connectionString.config** in your project and substitute it with an appropriate version on a pre-build msbuuild step.

We had a similair approach to handling environment-specific configuration files (so we had:

- web.**production**.config
- web.**staging**.config
- web.**debug**.config

  However, a pre-build step was used to pick one of this files and overwrite existing web.config  files, so when it came to execution/deployment/packaging system dealed with correct environment-specific config file, named **web.config**.

This approach is well described by Scott Hanselman [in his blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ManagingMultipleConfigurationFileEnvironmentsWithPreBuildEvents.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best thing is "config transformations". They are really easy to learn, very powerful ,you override only the portion of the web.config that is changing for that particular platform, and they are bundled with Visual Studio.
Take a look at this blog 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx

I hope that helps.